# JTable table structure changed

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

When I call `fireTableStructureChanged()` in a derived class of `AbstractTableModel`, the method `getValueAt(int row, int column)` is called with `row = -1`.

Should I just handle this by returning `null` or have I done something wrong with table or model configuration?

Comment: fireTableStructureChanged() reseting all, really all, resources, listeners, renderers, editors, value, result described in question could be real, true

Comment: have I done something wrong with table or model configuration? == your problem without an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for JTable (its XxxTableModel) in local variable

Comment: @mKorbel I couldn't understand a single thing you tried to explain...

Comment: post an SSCCE/MCVE or read Oracle tutorial - How to use Tables and [AbstractTableModel#fireTableStructureChanged()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableStructureChanged())

Comment: Row -1 is usualy meaning the header. So in this cas I would forward the call to the method `getColumnName(int)`.